# Merge two dataframes and keep both columns in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes.

```
a <- structure(list(sd.3.IID = structure(c(7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 
3L, 8L, 10L, 5L), .Label = c("0_62000_1", "0_62004_5", "0_62070_19", 
"0_62070_23", "0_62070_27", "0_62070_33", "ADNI_1092", "ADNI_1263", 
"ADNI_1283", "ADNI_1334"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")




 b <- structure(list(sd.3 = c("0_62000_1", "0_62004_5", "0_62070_19", 
"0_62070_23", "0_62070_27", "0_62070_33", "0_62071_1", "0_62071_15"
), sd.4 = c("0_62000_1", "0_62004_5", "0_62070_19", "0_62070_23", 
"0_62070_27", "0_62070_33", "0_62071_1", "0_62071_15"), sd.5 = c("0_62000_1", 
"0_62004_5", "0_62070_19", "0_62070_23", "0_62070_27", "0_62070_33", 
"0_62071_1", "0_62071_15")), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to merge these two and keep all column values based on `by.x = "sd.3.IID", by.y = "sd.3"`. I tried
`merge(x = a, y = b, by.x = "sd.3.IID", by.y = "sd.3", all = T)` but it doesn't keep `sd.3` column. What do I need to do to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `transform` to create a new column before the `merge` and change the `by.y` with the new column

```
merge(x = a, y = transform(b, sd.3t = sd.3), by.x = "sd.3.IID",
      by.y = "sd.3t", all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
   sd.3.IID       sd.3       sd.4       sd.5
1   0_62000_1  0_62000_1  0_62000_1  0_62000_1
2   0_62004_5  0_62004_5  0_62004_5  0_62004_5
3  0_62070_19 0_62070_19 0_62070_19 0_62070_19
4  0_62070_23 0_62070_23 0_62070_23 0_62070_23
5  0_62070_27 0_62070_27 0_62070_27 0_62070_27
6  0_62070_33 0_62070_33 0_62070_33 0_62070_33
7   ADNI_1092       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
8   ADNI_1263       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
9   ADNI_1283       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
10  ADNI_1334       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
11  0_62071_1  0_62071_1  0_62071_1  0_62071_1
12 0_62071_15 0_62071_15 0_62071_15 0_62071_15
```